# How to display entered description with special characters in software to report preview?

Tags: jasper-reports

We have enter the product description in application following below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the special character like `-----` or `=====`. Make use of report **`Line`** elements.

Drag a line element from the **`Pallete`** and place it in the editor in the desired position.

Then edit the properties.

In the **`Graphic Properties`** section,

Change the **`Pen`** type to draw different lines as *Dotted or Dashed* .

### Update:

Regarding the Alignment, Really there are multiple ways.

See the sample design, I use separate static text fields for displaying a `:`.

For the numeric values, keep them `Right Aligned`. If required, You can also add the **`Padding and Borders`** for the fields. Right Click on the field and select **`Padding and Borders`** option.

[image: Sample Design]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using struts2 how to get the correct output without alignment issue.

Comment: Are you using iReport tool to generate report template?

Comment: But i'm using in textarea. How is possible there?

Comment: How are you generating your jrxml file?

Comment: I'm using iReport tool version is 3.0.I'll generate this way.